# divide the window to display a software, always on top

Tags: c#, c++, c, windows, windows-7

This function is like the "always on top", it is something like always occupy the right most area.

I wrote a software that the software will pull some messages from server periodically, so I want to put it into the right-most area of the screen, and never be overwriten by other windows unless the user press the minimize button.

So it means the other windows, even the maximize button is pressed, will only occupy the left side of the screen(the space that not be occupied by my software).

Is it achievable in MS Windows?

Comment: why turning on "always on top" and positioning the window is not an option?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the support for [Application Desktop Toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144177(v=vs.85).aspx) is what you want:

> An application desktop toolbar (also called an appbar) is a window that is similar to the Windows taskbar. It is anchored to an edge of the screen, and it typically contains buttons that give the user quick access to other applications and windows. The system prevents other applications from using the desktop area used by an appbar. Any number of appbars can exist on the desktop at any given time.

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to make your window "always on top". You can't reserve part of the desktop exclusively for your application.